# Is it possible to take a snapshot of a processs and continue running on another machine?

Tags: linux, process

I have a program, when started, in the preparing stage, it will read some data only accessible on machine A, when preparing stage is done(calculation status and results are stored in the process memory), I want to distribute the program to other machines: B,C... and continue running. Is it possible?